# How to Join threads before exiting GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

If I have a GUI that uses multiple threads and I want to join them all before forcibly exiting (such as alt+f4), where do I set the command? Below is the code that I'm using to start the GUI but I suppose I can't put the join command before sys.exit(). Is there some conditions that need to be met or exceptions to catch to be able to wait for all the threads to join before exit?

Thank you for in advance for any help you can offer

```
if args.gui:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
    mainwindow = Application()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't think that Alt-F4 is a forced exit, although that also depends on the environment that you run your program in. In general, there should be a cleanup function invoked before program shutdown. Tell the threads to exit there and wait for them to finish. BTW, why do you suppose you can't join before `sys.exit()`?

Comment: What kind of threads are you using? `threading.Thread` objects are implicitly joined before the application exits, so you don't have to do anything special. If you're using `QThread`, you probably need to do extra work to make sure those `join` prior to exiting.

Comment: Sorry for this late answer. I'm indeed using threading.Thread. The situation I'm talking about is when pressing the cross to close the program. Since I'm using daemons they instantly crash which gives a lot of ugly error messages (normal threads would just hang). I tried to put the join function between mainwindow.show() and sys.exit(), but the program executes anything before sys.exit() instantly when it starts so it tried to join immediately upon starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you simply need to join other threads between the end of `app.exec-()` and the call to `sys.exit()`. Something like :

```
if args.gui:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
    mainwindow = Application()
    mainwindow.show()
    cr = app.exec_()
    # join other threads ...
    sys.exit(cr)
```